# Posting Data change to database from dynamic dropdown menu PHP

Tags: php, database, dropdown

I am SURE this has been answered here before but every search I make only gives me results for how to POST data FROM a db to a dynamic dropdown in php. I am needing to post my changes FROM the menu. IE make selection and have it update the database from a menu that is NOT a part of a form. Can someone lead me in the right direction please?

```
The code - 
foreach($Staff as $person){         
    $sf=$person->First_Name; 
    $sl=$person->Last_Name;
    $id=$person->id;
    echo("<option value = $sf&nbsp;$sl");
    if (($sf == $sf) && ($sl == $sl)) echo ("selected"); 
    echo(">$sf&nbsp;$sl</option>"); 
}
```

The above shows peoples names in a dropdown list. When I click on a selection in the list I need the database to update with their name and Id.

This is not relevant to the code, but elsewhere I have validation that ensures a user wants to make the change.

Comment: Not sure this relates to your issues really but `($sf == $sf)` is always going to be true. So is `$sl == $sl`. Not really sure what you were trying to do with those, to be honest

Comment: And `value = $sf&nbsp;$sl` is a mess. A) it needs quote marks round the value. And b) this should be the ID of the record, not the name. The name should be for display only

Comment: `from a menu that is NOT a part of a form`...well there's probably going to need to be some JavaScript involved then. Maybe Ajax too. Lack of more specific context makes it hard to give specific responses though

Comment: `($sf == $sf)` thanks. this is edited to protect the code, so the real name is different and not identical. `value = $sf&nbsp;$sl` This is first name and last name. If there is a better way, I am opened. `from a menu that is NOT a part of a form` I am opened to a suggestion as I am unsure where to go from here. I got the menu to populate and work but am lost beyond that

Comment: `If there is a better way, I am opened`...yes, use the ID as I already mentioned

Comment: `$sf == $sf) thanks. this is edited to protect the code, so the real name is different and not identical`...huh? All this does is check a variable against itself. So obviously it will always equal itself. It doesn't achieve a anything towards what you've said. It's not clear what you're trying to compare the name against.

Comment: `I am opened to a suggestion`...good. look into using JavaScript and AJAX then. As I already mentioned, I can't be more specific than that because you have been very vague about the current setup. All we have is some code to generate a drop-down list. Beyond that, nothing of substance to allow us to suggest anything meaningful. You could maybe use JavaScript to handle the "change" event of the drop-down, and then send the selected value to the server using Ajax

Comment: I am just trying to post the name change to the db. What would that look like?I dont know how to use the id otherwise I would have

Comment: The ID is right there on the line above! So just use it the same way as you did the name. e.g. `echo("<option value='$id'");`. I'm going to be brutally honest...if you can't work out how to switch one variable for another, having just been told fairly specifically what to do, then you will find programming very hard work in general.

Comment: And then find a JavaScript tutorial showing you how to handle the "change" event on a select. And then another about how to use Ajax with PHP so you can send the selected ID back to your server. This is stuff you need to learn by doing and practising. If you get stuck once you've attempted something, post your code here showing your attempt and explaining the specific problem. (I'm still assuming this is your best option btw, in the absence of any further info)

Comment: I do know how to program the JS event change. Just wasnt clear what you were suggesting on teh id change and then how to have the show the person's name too. Thanks